# Cannot update database using variable names?

Tags: php, sql

I just can't get this query to work when updating records in a mySQL database:

In my update script I POST the contents of two variables, and I can see the contents when I print them:

```
$orderno =$_POST['order_no'][$i];
$status =$_POST['order_status'][$i];
```

My SQL query looks like:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['order_status']))
{
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$orderno =$_POST['order_no'][$i];
$status =$_POST['order_status'][$i];
print_r($_POST['order_no']);
$sql = 'UPDATE Orders SET status="' . '$status'. '" WHERE   Orderno="' .'$orderno' . '"';
echo $sql;
mysql_select_db('PurchaseOrders');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
?>
```

This is inserting the variable name itself into the database and not the value of the variable which is printed? Many thanks

Comment: Please do not use the `mysql` functions as they're deprecated. Instead, use prepared statements with [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$sql = 'UPDATE Orders SET status="' . $status. '" WHERE   Orderno="' .$orderno . '"';
```

As well take into consideration security. You are not validating string (order number or status) in any shape or form.

As well mysql functions are deprecated, consider using mysqli

Comment: Hi, thanks for the responses, unfortunately my fields are not being populated

Comment: It is not very clear what is the value of $i is in your code, try checking that

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "UPDATE Orders SET status='" . $status . "' WHERE   Orderno= '" . $orderno . "' ";
```

When you encapsulate a variable in single quotes, PHP will take it "as is". It won't evaluate any variables found inside the quotes.

Have a look at the [difference between single quotes and double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/difference-between-single-quote-and-double-quote-string-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

use the query like this

```
$sql = "UPDATE Orders SET status='$status' WHERE  Orderno='$orderno'";
```

you are using variable inside `single quotes`. Inside `single quotes` variable name is not resolving, you have to use `double quotes` for this. In `double quotes` variable value is coming.